# python create a file in a directory errors

Tags: python

write a python program to create a .html file in a directory, the directory can be created correctly, use function open to create this .html file and try to write some content in this file,but the .html file can not be created,

```
def save_public_figure_page(self,type,p_f_name):

    glovar.date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d", time.localtime())
    p_f_page_file_directory = os.path.join("dataset", "html",type,glovar.date,p_f_name)
    data_storage.directory_create(p_f_page_file_directory)
    html_user_page = glovar.webdriver_browser.page_source
    p_f_page_file = os.path.join(p_f_page_file_directory,type + "_" + p_f_name + ".html")
    html_file = open(p_f_page_file, "w", encoding='utf-8')
    html_file.write(html_user_page)
    html_file.close()
```

the directory_create function in data_storage is:

```
#create the file storage directory
def directory_create(path):
    directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),path)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
```

it errors:

```
<class 'FileNotFoundError'> at /public_figure_name_sub
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:     'dataset\\html\\public_figure\\20170404\\Donald Trump \\public_figure_Donald     Trump .html'
```

the current directory is under /dataset/,  I found the directory:

```
  F:\MyDocument\F\My Document\Training\Python\PyCharmProject\FaceBookCrawl\dataset\html\public_figure\20170404\Donald Trump
```

has been created correctly,but the file——public_figure_Donald Trump .html can not be created correctly,could you please tell me the reason and how to correct

Comment: `Donald Trump ` has spaces in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jean-François Fabre, your file has a space just before the ".html".

To solve this, use `trim()` in the variable `p_f_name` in your 7th line:

```
# Added trim() to p_f_name
p_f_page_file = os.path.join(p_f_page_file_directory,type + 
                "_" + p_f_name.trim() + ".html")
```

This will create the file:

```
public_figure_Donald     Trump.html
```

instead of

```
public_figure_Donald     Trump .html
```

PD: Anyway your filename has a lot of spaces between Donald and Trump. I don't know where the file name comes but you might want to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

### Function save_public_figure_page

```
class public_figure:
    def save_public_figure_page(self, type, p_f_name):
        glovar.date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d", time.localtime())
        p_f_name = p_f_name.trim()  # Trim the name to get rid of extra spaces
        p_f_page_name = '{t}_{pfn}.html'.format(t=type, pfn=p_f_name)
        p_f_page_file_directory = os.path.join(
            directory,  # Add the directory from the data_storage.directory property
            "dataset", "html",
            type, glovar.date, p_f_name,
        )
        if data_storage.directory_create(self.p_f_page_file_directory):
            html_user_page = glovar.webdriver_browser.page_source
            p_f_page_file = os.path.join(p_f_page_file_directory, p_f_page_name)
            html_file = open(p_f_page_file, "w", encoding='utf-8')
            html_file.write(html_user_page)
            html_file.close()
```

### directory_create method of data_storage

```
#create the file storage directory
class data_storage:
    def directory_create(self, path):
        self.directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path)
        if not os.path.exists(self.directory):
            try:
                os.makedirs(self.directory)
            except:
                raise
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: You might want to explain your answer.